# How to deal with singular matrix in Local linear embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I'm getting singular matrix error while solving for the local weights using the  equation

```
Ci*Wi = 1
```

where Ci is the local co-variance matrix constructed from neighbors of point i and wi is the weight vector needed to construct the point i from its neighbors.

I'm using the IRIS dataset and number of neighbors is 20.

Comment: Why 20? Did you try changing number of neighbors?

Comment: If you are trying to solve a linear matrix equation, then Ci needs to be full-rank (and square) or otherwise this happens. I don't know what exactly you are doing, but you probably want a  least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation (working for under-, well-, or over- determined cases). In python, those two approaches would be [numpy.linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) and [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq).

Comment: Re-reading: when Ci is really a cov-matrix, it should be psd and solve should work, so double-check your Ci. (And maybe use some solving based on cholesky-factorization which is exactly for this case (matrix is psd) and numerically more stable than alternatives)

Comment: @ Jakub Bartczuk This is more of a general example. Yes,  I can decrease the number of neighbors. Is decreasing number of neighbors only solution? For example,  iris dataset has only four dimensions and we are left to choose 2,3,4 as number of neighbors.

Comment: @sascha  Yes covariance matrix should be psd. But after a bit of googling on this problem this is possible in case of LLE  [look here](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~jjcorso/t/555pdf/lleintro.pdf) [page 10 equation 6].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who comes here looking for answer.
This problem arises because weight gets concentrated to only few members. Few neighbors contribute heavily while other have zero contribution.
Add a regularizing term to penalize the larger weights. If your covariance matrix is C, regularization value is 0.0005 and I is an identity matrix of same order as C, update C using the formula below

```
C = C + 0.0005*I(n)
```